# Find $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\space$ as an exact answer for $\{a,b\} \in \mathbb R^+$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals, nested-radicals

(Sorry if my MathJax is strange, I just skimmed through the tutorial and tried to make it work)

I want to find what is basically a sum formula for square roots, similar how it exists for $\log(a) + \log(b)\text{, }\sin(a) + \sin(b)$ and $\cos(a) + \cos(b)$ but I am looking for $\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\space$. I am in pre-calc so I was wondering why such a formula was not already taught to me.

Ex. $\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}\space$ = some combination of radicals.

I tried it twice. The first try: 
$$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\space$$
$$= \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a*\frac ba}\space$$
$$= \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{a}*\sqrt{\frac ba}\space$$
$$= \sqrt{a}(1 + \sqrt{\frac ba})\space$$
But I didn't really get anywhere with that. So I tried it a second time with a different method.

Let $x = \sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\space$. Then I solved a system of equations w/ difference of squares and some FOIL.
$$x(\sqrt{a} - \sqrt{b}) = a-b$$
$$x(\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}) = a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b$$
Adding the equations,
$$2x\sqrt{a} =2a + 2\sqrt{ab}$$
$$x\sqrt{a} =a + \sqrt{ab}$$
But I said only positive real numbers in the title, so squaring both sides should be fine.
$$ax^2 = a^2 + 2a\sqrt{ab} + ab$$
$$x^2 = a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b$$
$$x = \sqrt{a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b}$$
$$\sqrt{a} + \sqrt{b}\space = \sqrt{a + 2\sqrt{ab} + b}$$
And it works, it eliminates the addition of square roots by forming a product. But I'm not sure if this was the most efficient way to solve it or if it works for all positive reals. Using the example, it works.
$\sqrt{2} + \sqrt{5}\space$ = $\sqrt{7 + 2\sqrt{10}}$ and that is true, both sides are about 3.65.
Is this a correct formula or am I missing something?

Comment: That is correct, but not of as much use as that of $\sin$'s or $\log$'s.

Comment: If $x$ is positive then $x=\sqrt {x^{2}}$ so it is obvious that $\sqrt  a+\sqrt b =\sqrt {(\sqrt  a+\sqrt b)^{2}}=\sqrt { a+2\sqrt {ab} +b}$.

Comment: There is a formula for $\sin a+\sin b$? I have heard of $\sin(a+b)$, but not the other way around. Also, $\ln a+\ln b=\ln ab$ is completely natural, as translating between addition and multiplication is, is some sense, what logarithms are _for_. The fact that it's difficult to find something sensible for $\sqrt a+\sqrt b$ or $\sqrt{a+b}$ is just another testament to the fact that multiplication and addition often get in one another's way (see the difficulty we have with describing the primes, or Fermat's last theorem for other examples).

Comment: @Arthur Here's a trig reference sheet I have bookmarked. Check page 2, right column: "sum to product formulas". http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/pdf/Trig_Cheat_Sheet.pdf

$$\sin \alpha + \sin \beta = 2 \sin \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2} \cos \frac{\alpha - \beta}{2}$$

Comment: @Arthur $\sin a+\sin b=2\sin\frac{a+b}2\cos\frac{a-b}2$.

Comment: Since there is no "direct" sum formula, you may rather be interested to ease computation by making use of common prime factors. For example, $\sqrt 3$ and $\sqrt{12}$ are both irrational but  $\sqrt 3 + \sqrt{ 12} = 3 \sqrt 3$ which leaves you with computing only one irrational number, and reduces errors in numerical computations. By the way, your formula would have led to a similar result since $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{36} = 6$ so you get rid of one root.